# How do I could start XD-LAB profile of Laboratory Domain

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hl7-cda, hl7-v3

**XD-LAB** is one of the most import profile of Laboratory Domain. I want to work with **XD-LAB** profile.

Here is some lacking of information as I am unable to start development of **XD-LAB** profile using **Apache Camel** and [*Open eHealth*](http://www.openehealth.org/display/ipf2/IPF+Introduction).

Do you have any demo/test case of Laboratory Document Sharing for `XD-LAB` profile.

Answer (score 1):

I am setting up a new company "clinicaldocumentengineering" together with two more partners, and we already have a tool on that, OpenCDABuilder. That, transform you current lab report to fulfill, for example, XD-LAB profiles. You can review a video demo at:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrEjhNFHfDQ

This tools mainly use OpenESB http://www.open-esb.net/, as working with HL7 CDA documents, need a tool that is able to deal with complex xml schema, and OpenESB is so good on that, as it's core data representation is xml and no transformations are required.

We also have a tool where to persists this documents directly as CDA that fulfils XD-LAB schematron, and then view them using Android or Web Viewer, and also query using SQL and get fore example, a patient laboratory evolution table based on CDA information.

Finally, just let me introduce you this tool form IHE, where to validate XD-LAB instances.

I hope this can be useful for you